# Random sampling probability of different colored balls

Tags: probability

Suppose there are 30 red balls and 20 green balls in a box. I want to take a random sample of 16 to 25 of these balls (with equal likelihood).

What is the probability that every ball in the sample is green? I know that here I want to condition on the size of the sample.

Now suppose that every ball in a random sample is green. What is the probability the sample size was 20? I know that here, the sample size could not be 21-25, but I am not sure how to proceed. I know I want to find the conditional probability of 20 given all green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Bayes:

$P[\text{sample size =20 }| \text{ all green} ] =\frac{P [\text{ all green} | \text{sample size =20} ] P [\text{sample size =20} ]}{P[ \text{ all green} ]}$

And total probabilities to compute $P[ \text{ all green} ]$

$P[ \text{ all green} ] = \sum\limits_{i=16}^{25}P [\text{ all green} | \text{sample size =i} ] P [\text{sample size =i} ]$